# Why are drm() predictions completely different when two outliers present?

Tags: r, regression, curve-fitting, drm, non-linear

I am using the drm() package to fit dose-response curves. I get an unexpected linear result from one dataset that has a classic sigmoid shape that should be a great fit. When I remove two outliers, drm() fits well. When I code non-linear regression by hand *with the outliers*, it fits well.

Why is drm() not working as expected when these two outliers are present? It should still capture the sigmoidal shape.

My data is the following:

```
xvals <- c(5.9e-10,1.32e-09,2.95e-09,1.47e-08,3.3e-08,7.37e-08,1.65e-07,3.69e-07,8.24e-07,1.84e-06,4.12e-06,9.22e-06,2.06e-05,4.61e-05,NA,5.9e-10,1.32e-09,2.95e-09,6.6e-09,1.47e-08,3.3e-08,7.37e-08,1.65e-07,3.69e-07,8.24e-07,1.84e-06,4.12e-06,9.22e-06,2.06e-05,4.61e-05,5.9e-10,1.32e-09,2.95e-09,6.6e-09,1.47e-08,3.3e-08,7.37e-08,1.65e-07,3.69e-07,8.24e-07,1.84e-06,4.12e-06,9.22e-06,2.06e-05,4.61e-05 )

yvals<-c(0.82966561,4.46055817,3.71339205,2.99750244,2.55537779,6.73492758,51.88282864,176.9312926,-46.02981355,-65.4610744,-65.14554737,-77.16448982,-66.20915802,-65.72309865,NA,10.11865308,1.33800105,1.25214635,1.58224315,3.88199733,7.57852483,0.76265989,5.56251398,18.70036528,-2.41340405,-47.71349527,-48.42671277,-49.38001241,-55.46415588,-59.49426595,4.84234111,5.17505193,3.76047711,0.67847071,17.52378196,11.90207166,2.36100264,9.13674669,18.1938161,-20.79653471,-70.00100539,-67.05360765,-51.15310137,-72.23892517,-50.99236881)
```

The two "outliers" that seem to be messing things up are the yvals  "51.88282864" and "176.9312926".

Using this code, I get this prediction:

```
df <- data.frame(xvals, yvals)
ldMod <- drm(yvals ~ xvals, data=df, fct = LL.4())
yhat <- predict(ldMod, df)

plot= ggplot(data=df, aes(x=xvals, y=yvals)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  geom_line(data=df, aes(x = xvals, y = yhat), linetype=2)

print(plot)
```

This gives this plot: [unexpected linear prediction from drm()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnOQC.png)

However, when I remove the two outliers by manually changing them to "NA", I get this plot
[expected sigmoidal prediction from drm()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlsIz.png).

This discrepency did not seem right, so I manually coded to perform a nonlinear regression using the hill model formula and optim() (which I know drm() uses as well). Then, I get the roughly the same results as drm() gave when I removed the outliers. This is the result I would expect:

```
#define formula
form <- function(theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3, x) {
  return(theta0 + (theta1 * ((x^theta2)/(theta3^theta2 + x^theta2))))
}

optim_ic = c(1,1,1,1)

min.rss <-  function(data, pars) {
  theta0 = pars[1]
  theta1 = pars[2]
  theta2 = pars[3]
  theta3 = pars[4]
  
  resid = y - (form(theta0, theta1, theta2, theta3, x))
  return(sum(resid^2))
}

m = optim(par = optim_ic,
          fn = min.rss,
          data = df,
          method = "Nelder-Mead",
          hessian = TRUE)

theta0hat <- m$par[1]
theta1hat <- m$par[2]
theta2hat <- m$par[3]
theta3hat <- m$par[4]

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=xvals, y = yvals)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) form(theta0hat, theta1hat, theta2hat, theta3hat, x))
```

[Expected result from non-linear regression by hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2shFp.png)

I have tried using different specifications with drm(), such as specificying robust methods like "lts", or telling it to use the "nelder-mead" algorithm. Nothing seems to help. Any ideas? Am I missing something with this package?